# Can't cancel repeat timer in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, timer, setinterval

I am trying to schedule a repeating timer in GWT, it will run every one milli second, poll for a certain event, if it is found satisfactory, do something and cancel the timer.
I tried doing this:

```
final Timer t = new Timer() {
    public void run() {
        if (..condition is true, exit) {
            t.cancel();
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
t.scheduleRepeating(1);
```

However, I get an error message like **the local variable t may not have been initialized**. I am putting tis piece of code in the `onSuccess` clause of a `RequestBuilder` callback.. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot access it while intializing itself.

change your code to

```
 final Timer fgf = new Timer() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                  cancel();
                  System.out.println();

            }
        };
```

Comment: Or in other words: `this` instead of `t`.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that I can call the `cancel` function on its own inside `run`..Thanks!

Comment: When cancel function() executing then timer will stop the working process. But when start the timer again then I will start with old data. Why time behaving like this?